# What proportion of lung compliance is attributable to alveolar surface tension?

Tags: human-physiology, pulmonology

I am reading Guyton and Hall, chapter 38, Pulmonary Ventilation. It states that the two main factors influencing lung compliance are 1) tissue elasticity 2) surface tension elastic force. An experiment is used to illustrate that one surface tension requires far more pressure to overcome during respiration than tissue elasticity, see diagram.

The text then states that because the pressure difference in the normal lung is about three times greater than the saline-filled lung (which has no surface tension effect, only tissue effects) that one can say that **lung elasticity** is only about one third tissue elasticity and two thirds due to surface tension elastic force.

My question is that **given lung compliance is the reciprocal of lung elasticity** does this mean that lung compliance is more due to tissue elasticity?

"Lung compliance is the volume change that could be achieved in the lungs per unit pressure change. [Lung e]lastance, also known as the elastic resistance is the reciprocal of compliance, i.e. the pressure change that is required to elicit a unit volume change. This is a measure of the resistance of a system to expand (Kahathudwa 2022)."

References:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvCHI.jpg): [image: StatPearls Pulmonary Compliance Lung Compliance Diagram]
[2] https://owlcation.com/stem/Lung-Compliance-and-Elastance

[3] Guyton and Hall Medial Physiology, Chapter 38.

[4] Stat Pearls, Pulmonary Compliance, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK538324/